# How to change the name of command button if clicked?

Tags: database, vb.net

i wanted to change the name of the "EDIT" button to "UPDATE" button and switch the function of the edit button to update button... someone please help...
here is my code:

```
If EDIT.Text = "Edit" Then
        TextBox8.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(1).Value()
        TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(2).Value()
        TextBox2.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(3).Value()
        TextBox3.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(4).Value()
        TextBox4.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(5).Value()
        TextBox5.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(6).Value()
        TextBox6.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(7).Value()
        ComboBox1.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(8).Value()
        TextBox9.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(9).Value()
        DataGridView1.Enabled = False
        EDIT.Text = "Update"
    ElseIf EDIT.Text = "Update" Then
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
        connect.Open()
        cmd.Connection = connect
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_book_info", connect)
        cmd.CommandText = "update tbl_book_info set (Title = '" & TextBox1.Text & "', Author = '" & TextBox2.Text & "',Copyright = '" & TextBox3.Text & "',Publisher = '" & TextBox4.Text & "',Place = '" & TextBox5.Text & "',Copies = '" & TextBox6.Text & "',Subject = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "',ClassNo = '" & TextBox8.Text & "',Registered = '" & TextBox9.Text & "',Time = '" & TextBox10.Text & "',Date = '" & TextBox11.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Done!")

        data = New DataTable()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = data

        da = New MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_book_info", connect)
        da.Fill(data)

        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        TextBox3.Text = ""
        TextBox4.Text = ""
        TextBox5.Text = ""
        TextBox6.Text = ""
        ComboBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox8.Text = ""
        TextBox9.Text = ""

        connect.Close()
    End If
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: sorry.. I already edited my question.

Comment: I think you mean you want to change the buttons text, not it's name.... and your code looks ok other than the fact you do not change it back to "Edit" when you click it in Update mode.

Comment: Always use SQL Parameters.  There are many opportunities for that code to fail. Try using a title like `A Hobbit's Tale`, you are also passing what ought to be numeric data - like copies - as text.